# PLSQL - How does this Prime number code work?

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE
   i number(3);
   j number(3);
BEGIN
   i := 2;
   LOOP
      j:= 2;
      LOOP
         exit WHEN ((mod(i, j) = 0) or (j = i));
         j := j +1;
      END LOOP;
   IF (j = i ) THEN
      dbms_output.put_line(i || ' is prime');
   END IF;
   i := i + 1;
   exit WHEN i = 50;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

The code works properly. I tried to figure out how it works and ended up having 4 as a prime number, which isn't. If you could help me understand how this nested loop works, I'd be very thankful.

Thank you.

Comment: What specifically, do you not understand?

Comment: Thank you all, my question is answered. I just got a little confused at one step but it's clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question.

When `i = 4` and `j = 2` then condition `((mod(i, j) = 0) or (j = i))` leads to the exit from inner loop, but condition `(j = i )` is false and program doesn't go to  line `dbms_output.put_line(i || ' is prime');`

Answer (score 2):

Lets rewrite it so its a bit simpler:

```
BEGIN
  <<outer_loop>>
  FOR value IN 2 .. 50 LOOP
    FOR divisor IN 2 .. value - 1 LOOP
      CONTINUE outer_loop WHEN MOD( value, divisor ) = 0;
    END LOOP;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( value || ' is prime' );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

All it is doing is, in the outer loop going through the number 2 .. 50 and in the inner loop is checking whether there is a number that divides exactly into that value; if there is then continue the outer loop and if there is not then output that the number is prime.

Your code is effectively the same code but it is complicated by not using `FOR .. IN ..` loops

Answer (score 2):

The code is looking for all the prime numbers up to 50. The outer loop is just checking each value of `i` from 2 to 50 to see if that integer is prime.

For each value of `i`, it tries to divide that integer by every other integer one by one, starting from 2. If `i` is divisible by `j` with no remainder (`mod` is zero) then it is *not* prime; unless it is only divisible by itself (`j=1`).

It exits that inner loop as soon as it finds a value of `j` which divides into `i`, or it reaches `i` itself.

It then needs a further check to see which of those conditions actually caused it to exit; and thus whether or not it is actually prime.

You could do the same thing with slightly clearer (IMHO) logic:

```
BEGIN
  <<OUTER>>
  FOR i IN 2..50 LOOP
    FOR j IN 2..i-1 LOOP
       IF (mod(i, j) = 0) THEN
         CONTINUE OUTER;
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
    dbms_output.put_line(i || ' is prime');
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```